# PHP Resource ID error

Tags: php, mysql, data-retrieval

I want to retrieve or output data in the database but I kept on getting the error called "Resource ID".

Here is my code:

```
<?php 

$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password ="123192";
$db_name = "customers";

//Connecting to your Host
mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password") or die("Failed To Connect The server");
//Selecting your Database
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("Failed To Select The DB");

$name = $_REQUEST['customerName'];

echo 'WELCOME! <b>'.$name.'</b> We hope that you\'ll Enjoy your stay ';

$sql="SELECT Name FROM `people` WHERE id =2 && Name = 'Kyel'";
$rs=mysql_query($sql);
echo "$rs";
?>
```

If I need improvement regarding my code kindly tell me.

Answer (score 4):

[`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns a resource. The *to string* (implicitly triggered by using `echo` to output it) of that is *Resource ID #* followed by the id.

A resource in PHP is only supposed to be used with other PHP functions. This includes but is not limited to file, curl, ftp handles, etc.

I could tell you to..

(a) use [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) (or similar) or

(b) use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

The latter is by far much better advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of the echo statement:

```
$array = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
var_dump ($array);
```

Comment: it gives me an array, I only want the data itself so that I could compare it with the userinput . I'll get data from the database and then Compare it with the user input. is that even possible? I wanted to retrieve data so that I can compare it with user input.

Comment: @user So you're saying you want to get the data from the database and compare it with user input?

Comment: Yes Precisely. that's the reason why I wanted to retrieve and get data from the database so that I can compare it with the user input

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["Name"];
}